# Codeigniter- Error while email send when using HTML type

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I found myself in a little problem. I am using codeigniter and process a mail function with HTML viewer but when i sent a mail, got its response true but it did not get in mail box.

My code is:
in Admin

```
    function sendEmail($to='',$subject='',$message, $fileUrl=''){
            $data['header']=$message[0];// Name 
            $data["message"]=$message[1];// Message in Text
            $data['image']=base_url()."assets/images/App-icon.jpg"; //logo

            $body = $this->load->view('emailtemplete',$data,TRUE);

            $from = "infomail@gmail.in";
            
            $this->load->library('email');

            
            $config['wordwrap'] = false;

            $config['mailtype']='html';
            $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
            $config['priority'] = '2';
            $this->email->initialize($config);
            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

            $this->email->from($from);
            $this->email->to($to);
            //$this->email->bcc($to);
            $this->email->bcc('mailerror@gmail.com');
            $this->email->subject($subject);
            $this->email->message($body,true);
            if(!empty($fileUrl))
            { 
                $this->email->attach($fileUrl);
            }
            $r=$this->email->send();
            if(!$r){
                print_r($this->email->print_debugger());
            }
    }
```

and emailtemplete.php is

```
<html></body>
<div><img src="<?php $image; ?>"></div><br/>
<div>Dear <?php $header ;?></div><br/>
<div><?php $message; ?></div>
</body</html>
```

Where am I making mistake in coading this. This code is work fine when its mailtype is text but when it is HTML, its not receiving.

Comment: Are you really using Gmail, or is that only for the example here?  If you are, you have to set SMTPHost, SMTPUser, SMTPPass, and SMTPPort.  http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html?highlight=email#sending-email